# How can I update the NSString property/variable after it changed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am confused about some items on the iOS developer site and require explanation. In the below cases A, B the property / variable is going to get updated, but it doesn't. [The page where the below code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1) resides.

These are the property/variable

- A) `self.badgeView.firstName`
- B)  `NSDate *originalDate`

These are the 2 snippets of code:

```
NSMutableString *nameString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"John"];   
self.badgeView.firstName = nameString; 
[nameString appendString:@"ny"];
NSDate *originalDate = self.lastModificationDate;
self.lastModificationDate = [NSDate date]; 
NSLog(@"Last modification date changed from %@ to %@", originalDate, self.lastModificationDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Those `NSString` properties, if implemented **The Right Way**, will *copy* the parameter you pass.

```
NSMutableString *nameString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"John"];   
self.badgeView.firstName = nameString; 
[nameString appendString:@"ny"];
// you'll have to update it again, if you want that view's string updated:
self.badgeView.firstName = nameString;
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply :)